# Why didn't this person kill this other person in Kick-Ass 2?

Tags: kickass

In 'Kick-Ass 2' The Motherf***er and his gang go to Colonel Stars and Stripes living quarters and they proceed to:

> kill Colonel Stars and Stripes and cut off his head

But, when they go to 'Night Bitches' house The Motherf***er and his gang

> only injure 'Night Bitch'

After they did what they did to Colonel Stars and Stripes The Motherf***er issued a warning to all other members of the when 'Battle Guy' says:

> We better start walking in pairs, The Motherf***er's Tweet said that this is  just the beginning...

It not like they needed her for the plot (maybe only as happily ever after with love interest Kick Ass) and The Motherf***ers intention were clear that he wanted to kill Kick-Ass and those around him, so I can't see why they spared her?

Was this just a plot issue or did I miss something as to why they left her alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent Word of God, or some explanation from a novelization or the comics, I suspect this falls under the tropes of [Spare A Messenger](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpareAMessenger) (warning! TVTropes will ruin your life!). If they kill everyone, there's no one to tell the story of how badass they are, and that they're coming after the others.

Other possibilities include appealing to the trope that, for women, the specter of sexual assault is more disturbing for some people than the idea that they might be killed. Or it could be battlefield pragmatism. Wounding a soldier takes them off of the field and forces their compatriots to devote mental and physical resources to their recovery, potentially sidelining multiple people. If Night Bitch had been killed, the others might have moved straight to revenge. As it is, now they have it nagging in the back of their mind as to how Night Bitch is recovering, providing a distraction.